# Compiling assimp with MinGW

Tags: dll, compilation, mingw, .a

I compiled [assimp](http://assimp.sourceforge.net/) with MinGW and I ended up with

1. 21mb of `libassimp.dll`
2. 42mb of `libassimp.dll.a`

Has anyone done this before? Why did I end up with such big files?
I comparison of the [VS compiled version](http://sourceforge.net/projects/assimp/files/assimp-3.0/assimp--3.0.1270-full.zip/download), they are relatively small ~ 2mb.

Comment: Are you building with the `-g` option in MinGW, which will incorporate symbol information?

Comment: If symbols are the problem, you should be able to use `strip` on the DLL to remove them; I'm not sure if it will work on the import library.

Comment: Ah, I didn't check. `-g` was there by default in the CMAKE for both release and debug variants.